# About openwrt dnscrypt

Tags: openwrt, certificates

I am self hosted a dnscrypt server, using dnscrypt-server-docker (https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-server-docker)

And i test it on my mac os x, it's work fine

```
$ sudo dnscrypt-proxy \                            
    --provider-key=xxxx \
    --resolver-address=xxxx:xxxx \
    --provider-name=2.dnscrypt-cert.xxxx.org 

[NOTICE] Starting dnscrypt-proxy 1.6.0
[INFO] Generating a new session key pair
[INFO] Done
[INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
[INFO] This certificate looks valid
[INFO] Chosen certificate #808464433 is valid from [2015-12-09] to [2015-12-10] [INFO] Server key fingerprint is xxxxx
[NOTICE] Proxying from 127.0.0.1:53 to xxxx:xxxx
```

But when i running it with openwrt, It's wrong.

```
[NOTICE] Starting dnscrypt-proxy 1.6.0
[INFO] Generating a new session key pair
[INFO] Done
[INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
[INFO] This certificate has not been activated yet
[ERROR] No useable certificates found
[INFO] Refetching server certificates
[INFO] Server certificate #808464433 received
[INFO] This certificate has not been activated yet
[ERROR] No useable certificates found
```

I try upgrade the dnscrypt-proxy, but does not work same.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timezone problem, So my certificates can't verify pass.

Solve: server and client using some timezone.